# Mongodb crashed! Where has my data gone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, mongodb

Please help!

Mongodb crashed on my server. When I started the `mongod backup` I have no data in database!

Looking at the `data/db/` directory I have the following 5 files:

```
mongo.lock
production-mongodb       4k
production-mongodb.0     64m
production-mongodb.1     128m
production-mongodb.ns    16m
```

I think mongo has somehow started a new database, keeping my old one? Hopefully! If this is correct how do I fix this? And what is going on here?

I have tried to remove the lock file and run `mongod --repair` but still empty database.

Comment: what version of mongodb were you running I did experience this too a few months back

Answer (score 0):

What does `show dbs` show? Did you switch to the correct DB assuming you see "production" listed?

Comment: i have local, admin and production-mongodb dbs but the production-mongodb has not data in and only 2 colleections ??

Answer (score -1):

OK, based on the files you've listed, you have one database named "production-mongodb".

So you'll want to run `mongod production-mongodb` to get command-line access.

Or you can do `mongod`

> use production-mongodb
>
> show collections

You should see your data.

Comment: he already stated that he sees his collection but his data isn't there.